# Updating values in current row using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i have this form that was fixed from previous post.

```
<form id="eForm" action="">
    <table class="fMain" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>        
            <tr class="ist">
                <td>In work</td>
                <td>09/25/2013</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="3500.00" name="salesS" class="totalS fo" readonly=""></td>                
                <td ><input type="text" value="23.00" name="cusS" class="cusS form-field-tiny readonly" readonly=""></td>
                <td>0.66%</td>                                         
            </tr>
            <tr class="ist">
                <td>In work</td>
                <td>09/25/2013</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="2445.00" name="salesS" class="totalS fo" readonly=""></td>                
                <td ><input type="text" value="444.00" name="cusS" class="cusS form-field-tiny readonly" readonly=""></td>
                <td>0.66%</td>                     
            </tr>                             
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

I am using following jQuery to do some formatting.

```
$('.eForm tr.ist').each(function () {
    var num = $(this).find('#salesS').val();
    var cNum = $(this).find('#cusS').val();
    alert(num);
    alert(cNum);
    document.getElementById('salesS').value = pC(num);
    document.getElementById('cusS').value = pC(cNum);
});
```

It is working fine all values are processed fine. But when it updates the values using
following lines it is not updating current row. It just updates the top row.

```
document.getElementById('salesS').value = pC(num);
document.getElementById('cusS').value = pC(cNum);
```

I tried this

```
$(this).find('#cusS').val()=pC(num);
```

It didn't work. Please let me know how to fix it so it updates values in current row. Thanks

Comment: Don't you mean `$('#eForm tr.ist').each`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jQuery is very wrong. Here's why :

```
$('.eForm tr.fMain').each(function () { // YOU GOT NO TR WITH THAT CLASS, It'S A TABLE

    var num = $(this).find('#salesS').val(); // YOU GOT NO ELEMENT WITH "salesS" ID
    var cNum = $(this).find('#cusS').val();// YOU GOT NO ELEMENT WITH "cusS" ID
    alert(num);
    alert(cNum);
    document.getElementById('salesS').value = pC(num); 
    document.getElementById('cusS').value = pC(cNum);
});
```

This code is wrong too :

```
$(this).find('#cusS').val()=pC(num);
```

It may be like this to be valid (if you'd have an input with cus5 id

```
$(this).find('#cusS').val(pC(num));
```

**Now what you may want is :**

```
$('.eForm tr.ist').each(function () { 
    var inputSales = $(this).find('input[name=salesS]');
    var inputCus =  $(this).find('input[name=cusS]');
    inputSales.val(pC(inputSales.val());
    inputCus.val(pC(inputCus.val());
});
```

Comment: Thank you for correction. It runs fine but only the first row gets updated twice. Even though it reads all rows values but last row value gets updated on first row only.

Comment: This you posted worked fine. $(this).find('#cusS').val(pC(num)); Thanks alot man